# I have a B1/B2 visa, when I entered the US the officer wrote B2, can i still attend the conference i was supposed to?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, conferences

I have a valid B1/B2 visa. When I came to the port of entry and described my purpose which includes meeting friends and also attending a conference at the end, the officer I think didn't pay attention to what I was saying and stamped it as B2. Can I still attend the conference?

Comment: Primary purpose for visit is what decides whether you're stamped B1 or B2.  Your answers probably led the officer to believe your primary purpose (or most of the time of visit) is visiting friends, and the conference is additional

Comment: If it is just to attend, it may not be categorized as a business visit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can attend the conference.

If you're *presenting* in a *trade* conference *on behalf of a business* and meeting a friend at the after-party, then B1 would probably have been more appropriate.

But in any case, I have never seen any CBP or ICE personnel standing at the conference entrances checking what the stamp says on people's passports.